# How to set onclick listener for animated image view

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I am developing an application which has animated image view moving from right to center.When click on image then OnClick() will be called. But when i click on the screen in image moving path(near to the image view) then also OnClick() fired. Please tell me how to set on click listener only for image view.
My code Is:

```
  ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            imageView=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.moveimage1);
    int width=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2;
    System.out.println("width==="+width);
            moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(width, 0, 0, 0);
            moveLefttoRight.setDuration(3000);
            moveLefttoRight.setRepeatCount(TranslateAnimation.INFINITE);  // animation repeat count
            moveLefttoRight.setRepeatMode(2);  

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println("Clicked");
                }
            });

imageView.startAnimation(moveLefttoRight);
 ll.addView(imageView);

        setContentView(ll);
```

Comment: what do mean do you want onClick() to fire while image view is animating or after animation completed

Comment: Is that imageview in the L1 linearLayout?

Comment: i want to fire onClick() when it is clicked.

Comment: yes boss. i is in ll layout.

Comment: I want to call that onClick() ,when we click on that image not in animation path.

Answer (score 0):

You attach the onclick listener once the animation has already finished.
For a more solid solution make a worker thread that handles all the computations that need to be done for the animation and only update the actual drawing on the main thread. E.g.:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors
        .newScheduledThreadPool(1);

// Execute the run() in Worker Thread every REFRESH_RATE
// milliseconds
mMoverFuture = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO - implement movement logic.
        if (moveWhileOnScreen()) {
            stop(false);
        }
        else {
            postInvalidate();
        }

    }
}, 0, REFRESH_RATE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

that way you can attach the onclick listener without it interfering with the movement.